# Card game vocabulary

Tags: online, terminology

I am building an online version of the [game of Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29), and I want to get my vocabulary straight. So far, the words I have are "card", "deck", "(card) feature", "set", "player" and "dealer".

I am missing words describing:

- the initial laying of 12 cards (lay out? initialisation?)
- the addition of 3 cards when a set has been found (add on? filler?)
- the set of cards that are face up, on the table (board? table?)
- the attempt made by a player to demonstrate a set (move? call? attempt?)
- the different types within a feature (variations?)

What are the technical terms used in card games, such as Set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Part of) the rules of Set read as follows:

> The dealer shuffles the cards and lays twelve cards (in a rectangle)
>   face up on the table so that they can be seen by all players. The
>   players remove a 'Set' of three cards as they are seen. Each 'Set' is
>   checked by the other players. If correct, the 'Set' is kept by the
>   player and the dealer replaces the three cards with three from the
>   deck. Players do not take turns but pick up 'Sets' as soon as they see
>   them. A player must call 'Set' before picking up the cards. After a
>   player has called 'Set', no other player can pick up cards until the
>   first player is finished. If a player calls 'Set' and does not have
>   one, the player loses one point. The three cards are returned to the
>   table.

As such, I'd recommend for your terms: (1) layout, or possibly deal; (2) replacement; (3) the cards [on the table]; (4) calling 'Set'; and (5) variation.  (Not in the above paragraph, but earlier in the rules I'm looking at, it states "Each card has a variation of the following four features".

Answer (score 1):

> (1) layout, or possibly deal; (2) replacement; (3) the cards [on the table]; (4) calling 'Set'; and (5) variation.

I agree with these terms. You might add another for the Sets each player holds until scoring at the end of a round. Per the rules of Set, in the scoring portion:

> The number of 'Sets' held by each player are then counted, one point is given for each and added to their score.

Though if you simply score in real time, you may not need this mechanism.